# How to optimize the multiple conditions in a list search that are conflicting in python?

Tags: python, list, search, conditional-statements

I am making a phone book searching program in python that searches a text file for the name input for school. In the program, the user is asked for a last name or first and last name. The program will then search the text file and print the names that match the input given with their phone number.

 
So if the user input Adams, the result would be: 
John Adams, 508-555-5555 
Quicy Adams, 508-555-5556

 If the user input John Adams, then it would only print his name. 
John Adams, 508-555-5555

 My problem is that with my conditions for the for loop that reads the list line by line. It will print all names that match the last name regardless if a full name is used.

 Here is my code:

```
while True:
    original_name = input("Enter a last name, or first and last name: ")  # prompt user for name

    if original_name == "":   # create condition for infinite loop to end
        break

    l_name = original_name.lower()  # lower case to assist in finding a match
    s_name = l_name.split()         # split to allow a full name to become two variables

    if len(s_name) == 1:        # Set condition for last name if it is by itself to be properly placed in variable
        last_name = s_name[0]
    elif len(s_name) == 2:      # Set condition for first name and last name to go into proper variables
        first_name = s_name[0]
        last_name = s_name[1]
    else:
        print("Error: Input needs to be no more than 2 names!")  # error for when more than 2 names are given

    f = open("phones.txt", 'r')     # open text file being used
    numbers = f.readlines()         # read text file line by line

    for line in numbers:
        line = line.lower()     # lower case to assist in finding a match
        line = line.strip()     # strip to get rid of new lines
        line = line.split()     # split to allow for both first and last name to match

        if line[1] == last_name in line:    # This condition is to ensure a line is printed if only a last name is used
            print(line[0].capitalize(), line[1].capitalize(), ",", line[2])
        elif line[1] == last_name and line[0] == first_name in line: # when a first and last name is used
            print(line[0].capitalize(), line[1].capitalize(), ",", line[2])
        else:       
            continue
```

I know that my problem is with the conditionals. If I use the elif condition first, it will print the names with the same last name even if the full name is used. 
 I have looked at a few questions on stackflow to see if I could figure it out, but none fully matched my issue. Also, I am wondering how to get the comma closer to the last name, since my output has it float a whitespace forward of the last name: John Adams , 508-555-5555. 
I appreciate all help given and look forward to the knowledge you will impart!

Comment: Have you tried reading the list in once, then turning it into a python object (like a dict or something) that you can work with in memory?

Comment: Some of these tests don't make much sense.  For example, `line[1] == last_name in line`.  This is equivalent to `line[1] == last_name and last_name in line`, which in turn is equivalent to `line[1] == last_name`.  The additional test that it be in `line` is pointless since you already know it is if the first condition is met.

Comment: @TomKarzes Ah, I wasn't aware of the logic in that statement. I will keep it in mind for my future conditionals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something along the lines of:

```
if (len(s_name) == 2 and first_name == line[0] and last_name == line[1]) or (len(s_name) == 1 and last_name == line[1]):
    print(line[0].capitalize(), line[1].capitalize(), ",", line[2])
```

This will print the line if two names are provided and the 2 match or if 1 name is provided and it matches the last name. Worth noting for each element in the line lsit you probably want to do strip as to avoid the element snot mathcing due to whitespace.

Comment: Thank you Carlos! I implemented your condition and it works wonderfully. I still have an issue with the comma in print, but that's not world ending. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Why bother so much as to get last names first names? try this:

```
while True:
    if input("name").lower() in line.lower():
        print(line)
```

EDIT

```
def search(name):
    with open('phones.txt','r') as file:
        temp=[]
        for i in file :
            if name in i :
                temp.append(i.split())
        for i in temp:
            i[0]=i[0]+' '+i[1]
            i[1]=', '
            print(''.join(i))
```

Comment: The issue I see is that it wouldn't meet the formatting needs that I was asked for. Since the text file does not have a comma after the last names, I have to add it in with the program.

Comment: so the data is : abc def xxxxxxxxx??

Comment: Yes. So: John Adams 508-555-5555

Comment: Check this new EDIT. If this is answers the question remember to accept it as solution.